# Textmate shortcut/macro for selecting HTML tag's contents?

Tags: macros, textmate, hotkeys, textmate2

Is there a Textmate shortcut or macro for selecting an HTML tag's contents?

`<p>Everything</p>`

So, for the above, "Everything" would be selected.

Bonus points if you know of a shortcut or macro that also selects everything *including* the tags.

Surprised these aren't in the HTML bundle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bundle by this guy http://inquirylabs.com/blog2009/my-textmate-bundle/ that will do that for you.

Default hotkey is cmd right arrow... once you have the tag you want highlighted hit tab and it will select its contents.